# Does phonegap has one main webview object?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile

In phonegap projects can we add more than one webview, which will load html,css and javascript separately.

for eg webview1 will load first.html file and webview2 can load second.html.

Also if i do this will it help in improving the app performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need only one WebView - there you can load different html files, but that definitely will not improve the performance.

For better performance you can compress your js and css files.

Comment: Thanks darin. suppose if someone says "each module running through one main webview object". thus this mean that i have only one webview in my app?